# User can't access own private files via Views

Tags: 7, files

I've set up a private directory *sites/default/files/private* and use it for a file field.

As an admin, everything works as expected when uploading and viewing a private file.

As a user who uploads a private file, I can only download own private files with the Views formatter *Download link* (example.com/file/585/download?token=TcBjzT2I), but not view them via *Generic file* (example.com/system/files/private/mypic.jpg) or other formatters. When using the latter, I get

"Access Denied
You are not authorized to access this page."

Permission "View own private files" for role enabled. Even enabling "View private files" has no effect.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

> Files in the private directory are not accessible directly through the web server;

You may have to use [file_create_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7.x) or [hook_file_download](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7.x) to access the files under private directory.

For More info on **Accessing Private Files** check [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/file/overview)

Comment: Thanks, Kstack. What I don't understand is why can the admin view the files then?